# Two implementations of a method? (VS2012 + ReSharper 7.1)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper-7.1

When I right-click a method and select *Go to Implementation* I am often presented with two implementations; one in my source code and one as a reference...

[image]

> In this example, `EmailService` is in a different project that is loaded into the current Visual Studio solution and referenced as a project reference.

Selecting the reference one seems to do nothing, whereas selecting the source code one takes me to the implementation of the method (as expected).

This has happened on a couple of different development machines, in different projects.

What is causing this, and is it possible to resolve the issue so that *Go to Implementation* takes me directly to the source code implementation?

This is happening in Visual Studio 2012 with ReSharper 7.1 installed.

Comment: I've also seen this in VS2010 + R# 7.1

Comment: My guess would be that there are problems with Project References versus Assembly References - have a look at your `csproj` in notepad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Alt-Shift-T` or whatever you have for symbol search, is the checkbox for include library types selected?

If not, then it may be [this Resharper bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-328957). You can help fixing it if you create a small reproducible example and attach there ;)